# How to access 'Enum' column data type in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, enums, sqlalchemy

I have created set of tables using SQLAlchemy's MetaData().

I used SQLAlchemy's Enum as a data type for some columns:

```
from sqlalchemy import Enum
```

In my MySQL database I could see the data type being Enum. For example:

```
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
number of cords enum('1','2','3')
```

Column name being: `number of cords` and data type: `enum('1','2','3')`

However, when I try to access the data type it returns VARCHAR!

This is how I access data types:

```
tables = metadata.sorted_tables
for table in tables:
    for column in table.columns:
        print("TYPE: "+str(column.type ))
```

Prints:

```
TYPE: VARCHAR(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out for MySQL I need to import this:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import ENUM
```

Based on [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#mysql-data-types) doc.